# Create 'top 3' list of ints with corresponding percentages

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am creating a personality quiz that takes the users multiple choice answers and adds to these tallies each time they choose a corresponding answer:

```
public static int SubTally = 0;
public static int DomTally = 0;
public static int SimTally = 0;
public static int GroTally = 0;
public static int DefTally = 0;
public static int AccTally = 0;
public static int ConTally = 0;
```

After it does the logic to add to these, I create a list from these and choose the max as the answer:

```
List<int> MyList = new List<int> 
{ 
   SubTallyResult, 
   DomTallyResult, 
   SimTallyResult, 
   GroTallyResult, 
   DefTallyResult, 
   AccTallyResult, 
   ConTallyResult 
};
int max = MyList.Max();
```

I now want to take the top three highest tallies and take each one, divide by the total, and multiply by 100 in order to get their percentages. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Using this process is going to cause an headache once you attempt to identify which of the three represent which tally...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OrderByDescending` to sort in descending order then `Take` 3 elements and get the required output like:

```
var total = MyList.Sum();
var query = MyList.OrderByDescending(r=> r)
                  .Take(3)
                  .Select(r=> new 
                   {
                    Number = r, 
                    Percentage = ((double)r / total) * 100d,
                   });
```

Comment: How could I then say which corresponds to which percentage? I was thinking to return a string and do:   return "1st:"+query.first+"query.first.percentage" etc....(i know this is incorrect syntax, I am new to C#)

Comment: @Christian, you will only get the number, since it is a `List<int>`, you will never know if it is `DomTally` or `SubTally`, and That itself is an issue, otherwise if you are only interested in the actual value then you can do `foreach(var item in query) { Console.Write(item.Number + "," + item.Percentage);}`

Comment: How can I better do this so that I can find out which tally goes to which percentage? Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may face issues later on identifying which tally is in the top three, here's an alternative approach.

```
void Example()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    List<Tally> tallies = new List<Tally>
    {
        new Tally("SubTally", random.Next(0,100)),
        new Tally("DomTally", random.Next(0,100)),
        new Tally("SimTally", random.Next(0,100)),
        new Tally("GroTally", random.Next(0,100)),
        new Tally("DefTally", random.Next(0,100)),
        new Tally("AccTally", random.Next(0,100)),
        new Tally("ConTally", random.Next(0,100))
    };

    int sum = tallies.Sum(tally => tally.Score);
    var topThreeTallies = tallies.OrderByDescending(tally => tally.Score)
           .Take(3)
           .Select(tally => new 
           {
                tally.Name,
                tally.Score,
                Percentage =  ((decimal) tally.Score / sum) * 100M
            });

}

public class Tally
{
    public Tally(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public Tally(string name, int score)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Score = score;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I return that top 3 tallies list? Was that done in another program just for example?

Comment: @Christian are you mentioning the images? If so, I use an application called `LinqPAD`, it's a scratchpad for `C#`, `F#` & `VB`.... It's a must have for writing up quick proof of concepts... http://www.linqpad.net/ I highly recommend that you purchase the `Premium version` if your budget allows due to the additional features it provides, if not, there is  a free version to. If you install LinqPAD, visit this link: http://share.linqpad.net/3d7xs7.linq that will demonstrate how I dumped out the results.